# Postgresql - concat_ws like function?

Tags: postgresql

I'm having a first painful experience with postgresql, and the minute-challenge of the moment is :

How to perform a [concat_ws](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) in postgresql, to join several fields value from a group by :

```
select concat_ws(';',field_lambda) from table_lambda group by id;
```

Comment: FYI, concat_ws will be in PostgreSQL 9.1: http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/functions-string.html

Comment: .. but in Postgres `concat_ws()` is *not* an aggregate function. Use `string_agg()` instead. See below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For PostgreSQL 8.4 and above:

```
select ARRAY_TO_STRING(
    ARRAY_AGG(field_lambda),';'
) from table_lambda group by id;
```

Answer (score 8):

Postgres **9.0** added the aggregate function [**`string_agg()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) for the job:

```
SELECT string_agg(field1, ';') FROM tbl GROUP BY id;
```

The second parameter is the separator (similar to other aggregate functions).
See:

- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#15850510)

The string function [**`concat_ws()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) (Postgres 9.1+) does the same as MySQL's `concat_ws()` - when not abused as aggregate function. It's particularly useful to deal with null values:

```
SELECT concat_ws(';', field1, field2, field3) FROM tbl
```

You could even combine both to aggregate multiple columns:

```
SELECT id, string_agg(concat_ws(',', field1, field2, field3), ';') AS fields
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `array_agg` (before 8.4), you can use:

```
SELECT array_to_string(
    ARRAY(SELECT field_lambda FROM table_lambda GROUP BY id), ';'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [PostgreSQL wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Array_agg), you can emulate the PostgreSQL 8.4 `array_agg` function to get close to what you need.

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg(anyelement) (
    SFUNC=array_append,
    STYPE=anyarray,
    INITCOND='{}'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for;
the tag data must show that asset has several, that is, for asset 6, which has 2 tags, show them 1,2
being the table:

asest_id         1     1     1     6     6

tag_id           1     3     5     1     2

SELECT asset_tag.asset_id,asset_tag.tag_id,
concat_ws(',',asset_tag.tag_id,asset_tag.tag_id) AS etiqueta

FROM    public.asset_tag

--JOIN PUBLIC.imagen ON asset_tag.asset_id = imagen.asset_id

--WHERE imagen.asset_id = asset_tag.asset_id

GROUP BY asset_tag.asset_id,asset_tag.tag_id ;

Answer (score -1):

Further people coming here for this problem, this method would not work with multiple columns(like concat_ws would) if you want to support multiple colums use

```
ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY[$columns_string], 'my_delimiter').
```