# Postgresql GROUP_CONCAT equivalent?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-concat, string-aggregation

I have a table and I'd like to pull one row per id with field values concatenated.

In my table, for example, I have this:

```
TM67 | 4  | 32556
TM67 | 9  | 98200
TM67 | 72 | 22300
TM99 | 2  | 23009
TM99 | 3  | 11200
```

And I'd like to output:

```
TM67 | 4,9,72 | 32556,98200,22300
TM99 | 2,3    | 23009,11200
```

In MySQL I was able to use the aggregate function `GROUP_CONCAT`, but that doesn't seem to work here... Is there an equivalent for PostgreSQL, or another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Not an answer, but check out http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/14-CrossTab-Queries-in-PostgreSQL-using-tablefunc-contrib.html.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943433/postgresql-concat-ws-like-function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: I think the best answer is still in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47638417/243233

Answer (score 316, accepted):

This is probably a good starting point (version 8.4+ only):

```
SELECT id_field, array_agg(value_field1), array_agg(value_field2)
FROM data_table
GROUP BY id_field
```

[array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) returns an array, but you can CAST that to text and edit as needed (see clarifications, below).

Prior to version 8.4, you have to define it yourself prior to use:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg (anyelement)
(
    sfunc = array_append,
    stype = anyarray,
    initcond = '{}'
);
```

(paraphrased from the PostgreSQL documentation)

Clarifications:

- The result of casting an array to text is that the resulting string starts and ends with curly braces.  Those braces need to be removed by some method, if they are not desired.
- Casting ANYARRAY to TEXT best simulates CSV output as elements that contain embedded commas are double-quoted in the output in standard CSV style. Neither array_to_string() or string_agg() (the "group_concat" function added in 9.1) quote strings with embedded commas, resulting in an incorrect number of elements in the resulting list.
- The new 9.1 string_agg() function does NOT cast the inner results to TEXT first.  So "string_agg(value_field)" would generate an error if value_field is an integer.  "string_agg(value_field::text)" would be required.  The array_agg() method requires only one cast after the aggregation (rather than a cast per value).

Comment: And in 9.0 you will have listagg()

Comment: To get CSV the query should be: 
SELECT id_field, array_to_string(array_agg(value_field1), ','), array_to_string(array_agg(value_field2),', ')
FROM data_table
GROUP BY id_field

Comment: You can't use array_to_string in all cases here.  If your value_field contains an embedded comma, the resulting CSV is incorrect.  Using array_agg() and casting to TEXT properly quotes strings with embedded commas.  The only caveat is that it also includes the starting and ending curly braces, hence my statement "and edit as needed".  I will edit to clarify that point.

Comment: FYI: here's a link to [docs on array_agg in 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)

Answer (score 410):

[Since 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) this is even easier:

```
SELECT id, 
       string_agg(some_column, ',')
FROM the_table
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Note that the syntax also allows you to specify the order of values in the string (or array, using `array_agg`) e.g. `string_agg(some_column, ',' ORDER BY some_column)` or even `string_agg(surname || ', ' || forename, '; ' ORDER BY surname, forename)`

Comment: It's awesome that `distinct` works with string_agg, so one can use `string_agg(distinct some_solumn, ',')`

Comment: Note that you may need to cast the column value to `TEXT` if it is a non-stringable value (ie. `uuid`). This would look like `string_agg(some_column::text, ',')`

Comment: If column type is integer, don't forget to convert or use concat(column, '') for implicit conversion

Comment: PS, string_agg(value, ',') can be use only if the `value` is string.
For example, if the `value` is integer `value` need to be casted to string like `value::character varying`

Comment: hello, I need some help when I do that, of course its the same result, example: "60-70,60-70,60-70,60-70" in the same column, but how can I that only appear once? "60-70" I used string_agg

Answer (score 61):

```
SELECT array_to_string(array(SELECT a FROM b),', ');
```

Will do as well.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent#comment23843695_8803563), where you aggregate in a certain order? How would you handle grouping by one column and ordering by another one (for example, to concatenate variables within a longitudinal data set)?

Answer (score 31):

Try like this:

```
select field1, array_to_string(array_agg(field2), ',')
from table1
group by field1;
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that the table **your_table** has three columns (name, id, value), the query is this one:

```
  select name, 
         array_to_string(array_agg(id), ','), 
         array_to_string(array_agg(value), ',')
    from your_table
group by name
order by name
;

"TM67"  "4,9,72"    "32556,98200,22300"
"TM99"  "2,3"       "23009,11200"
```

KI

Answer (score 3):

and the version to work on the **array type**:

```
select
  array_to_string(
    array(select distinct unnest(zip_codes) from table),
    ', '
);
```

Comment: Duplicate answer, @max_spy said the same thing five years ago

Comment: @EmilVikström: you have right to be wrong, but read carefully. It's not only different, but I gave an example, which works with array type - like zip_codes being `character varying(5)[]`. Also, I've verified that for my purpose - unnest is needed, otherwise you will see `ERROR:  cannot accumulate arrays of different dimensionality`.

Comment: @Sław It would be cleaner (on this page) for you to eduacationally explain the uniqueness, intent, and purpose of your answer by editing your answer (not explaining via comment).

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, I had bigint as column type. So The below code worked for me. I am using PostgreSQL 12.

**Type cast is happening here. (::text)**.

```
string_agg(some_column::text, ',')
```

Answer (score 1):

My sugestion in postgresql

```
SELECT cpf || ';' || nome || ';' || telefone  
FROM (
      SELECT cpf
            ,nome
            ,STRING_AGG(CONCAT_WS( ';' , DDD_1, TELEFONE_1),';') AS telefone 
      FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT * 
            FROM temp_bd 
            ORDER BY cpf DESC ) AS y
      GROUP BY 1,2 ) AS x
```

Comment: Why are you doing `ORDER BY` in an inner query? Won't the ordering get lost anyway?

Answer (score -2):

Hope below Oracle query will work.

```
Select First_column,LISTAGG(second_column,',') 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY second_column) as Sec_column, 
    LISTAGG(third_column,',') 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY second_column) as thrd_column 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY first_column
```

Comment: I tested it on https://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler and didn't work: 42883: function listagg(text, unknown, text) does not exist

Comment: Oracle has different syntax and functions than postgres.