# PostgreSQL query to return results as a comma separated list

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let say you have a `SELECT id from table` query (the real case is a complex query) that does return you several results.

The problem is how to get all `id` return in a single row, comma separated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgresql GROUP_CONCAT equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent)

Comment: The above "dupe" was relevant and useful, especially the `array_agg()` function in particular.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

`SELECT string_agg(id::text, ',') FROM table`

Requires PostgreSQL 9.0 but that's not a problem.

Comment: Note that for me at least, string_agg didn't like taking an int for its first argument so I did something like: `string_agg(CAST(id as varchar), ',')` instead.

Comment: @JZC, or even easier: `string_agg(id::text, ',')`

Comment: If you wanted to sort the column
`select string_agg(id, ', ' order by id desc) from table`

Comment: I ran into duplicates with my query but solved it with `STRING_AGG(DISTINCT customer_name, ',')`

Answer (score 59):

You can use the array() and array_to_string() functions togetter with your query.
With `SELECT array( SELECT id FROM table );` you will get a result like: {1,2,3,4,5,6}

Then, if you wish to remove the {} signs, you can just use the array_to_string() function and use comma as separator, so: `SELECT array_to_string( array( SELECT id FROM table ), ',' )` will get a result like: 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: ``SELECT array_to_string( id,  ',' ) AS id FROM table``

Answer (score 17):

You can generate a CSV from any SQL query using psql:

```
$ psql
> \o myfile.csv
> \f ','  
> \a
> SELECT col1 AS column1, col2 AS column2 ... FROM ...
```

The resulting myfile.csv will have the SQL resultset column names as CSV column headers, and the query tuples as CSV rows.

h/t http://pookey.co.uk/wordpress/archives/51-outputting-from-postgres-to-csv

Answer (score 5):

Use this below query it will work and gives the exact result.

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(id), ',') FROM table
```

**Output** : {1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

use array_to_string() & array() function for the same.

```
select array_to_string(array(select column_name from table_name where id=5), ', ');
```

Comment: How is this better than using `string_agg()`?

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT array_agg(id, ',') FROM table
```

> {1,2,3,4}

I am using Postgres 11 and EntityFramework is fetching it as array of integers.