# Return one row with many records from right table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables.  One is a listing of products, and one is a listing of their many attributes.  (This has been simplified from my original model. ;) )

Table `prods` has two columns: `id` and `name`.
Table `taxons` has three columns: `id`, `name`, and `prod_id`.

`Prods` has four records:

```
id | name
= = = = = =
 1 | boat
 2 | tree
 3 | lamp
 4 | soda
```

`Taxons` has fifteen records:

```
 id |   name    | prod_id
= = = = = = = = = = = = = =
 1  | bright    | 3
 2  | breezy    | 1
 3  | green     | 2
 4  | wet       | 1
 5  | sturdy    | 2
 6  | shady     | 2
 7  | antique   | 3
 8  | deciduous | 2
 9  | buoyant   | 1
 10 | fizzy     | 4
 11 | calming   | 2
 12 | carefree  | 1
 13 | big       | 1
 14 | sweet     | 4
 15 | brass     | 3
```

What I would like is a query that join `taxons` onto `prods` using `prods.id` and `taxons.prod_id`, but only return 4 rows, so something like this:

(Desired) Result:

```
1 | boat | breezy | wet     | buoyant | carefree  | big
2 | tree | green  | sturdy  | shady   | deciduous | calming
3 | lamp | bright | antique | brass
4 | soda | fizzy  | sweet
```

I'm not sure where to go with this, I've tried various combinations of unions and joins, but haven't found anything that works.  We're using postgres.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to adapt the `GROUP_CONCAT` equivalents in this article:

[Postgresql GROUP_CONCAT equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent)

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  :)  I thought I had searched high and low! Ended up doing something like this: SELECT p.name, array_agg(t.name) as prod_taxons FROM prods as p LEFT JOIN taxons as t ON p.id = t.prod_id GROUP BY p.name;

Answer (score 3):

To get all of the values in one column you can use `array_agg()`:

```
select p.id, array_agg(t.name) list
from prods p
inner join taxons t
   on p.id = t.prod_id
group by p.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e6ed0/6)