# How do I get unique user engagements?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I am trying to list unique `user engagements` with the `engagement_type`

I used to have the following query.

```
SELECT u.id, u.fname, u.lname FROM (
  SELECT id, engagement_type FROM (
    SELECT user_id AS id, 'comment'
    FROM comments WHERE commentable_id = 48136 AND commentable_type = 'Video'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id AS id, 'like'
    FROM likes WHERE likeable_id = 48136 AND likeable_type = 'Video'
  ) AS a
  GROUP BY id
  LIMIT 10
) b JOIN users u USING (id);
```

Returns:

```
id        | fname      | lname
------------------------------
1         | joe        | abc
2         | sarah      | qer
3         | megan      | tryey
4         | john       | vdfa
```

Which is fine. Now, I want to include the engagment type. I've come up with this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.fname, u.lname, engagement_type FROM (
  SELECT id, engagement_type FROM (
    SELECT user_id AS id, 'comment' AS engagement_type
    FROM comments WHERE commentable_id = 48136 AND commentable_type = 'Video'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id AS id, 'like' AS engagement_type FROM likes
    WHERE likeable_id = 48136 AND likeable_type = 'Video'
  ) AS a
  GROUP BY id, engagement_type
  LIMIT 10
) b JOIN users u USING (id);
```

Which now returns:

```
id        | fname      | lname    | engagement_type
---------------------------------------------------
1         | joe        | abc      | comment
2         | sarah      | qer      | like
3         | megan      | tryey    | like
4         | john       | vdfa     | like
1         | joe        | abc      | like     
3         | megan      | tryey    | comment
```

The only problem with above. The results are not unique anymore. As you can see, Joe and Megan have 2 entries.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: try removing `engagement_type` from `GROUP BY` clause and check if meets your needs.

Comment: however, `joe` had two unique engagements viz, `comment` & `like`. So did `megan`.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Do you want to display only one engagement_type or list like "comment, like"?

Comment: Your b subquery is grouped `BY id, engagement_type`, that's why you're getting more than one row per user. You could change the LIMIT to 1 to fudge it to only one row, but which one do you really want (as Jakub says)?

Comment: You failed to define what you want to show for `engagement_type` if there are multiple.

Comment: If you want to put all the distinct engagement types on the same single line per user, you probably want to take a look at this question: [Postgresql GROUP_CONCAT equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent)

Comment: I want to display one engagement_type. Not a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler with `DISTINCT ON` in PostgreSQL.
For lack of definition I pick the first `engagement_type` according to its sort order:

```
SELECT u.id, u.fname, u.lname, b.engagement_type
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
          id, engagement_type
   FROM (
      SELECT user_id AS id, 'comment' AS engagement_type
      FROM   comments
      WHERE  commentable_id = 48136
      AND    commentable_type = 'Video'

      UNION ALL
      SELECT user_id, 'like'
      FROM   likes
      WHERE  likeable_id = 48136 
      AND    likeable_type = 'Video'
      ) a
   ORDER  BY 1, 2
   LIMIT  10
   ) b
JOIN users u USING (id);
```

Details, links and explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

If you want a *unique list* of all engagement_types:

```
  SELECT id, string_agg(DISTINCT engagement_type, ', ') AS engagement_types
   FROM (
      ...
      ) a
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY <whatever>
   LIMIT  10;
```

[`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) need Postgres 9.0 or later.
This form allows to order by whatever you want, while you'd need another subquery if you want `ORDER BY` to disagree with `DISTINCT ON`.

Comment: Very nice solution. Appreciate it!

Comment: Just one thing how does the `ORDER BY` work here? What if I wanted to order by most recent engagements. How would I go about that?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini: Follow the link. I wrote a detailed explanation at the related answer that should cover it. Start by defining "most recent". There is nothing in the question to cover that.

Comment: "Most recent", sorted by the newest engagements. Ideally, via the `created_at` column. However, I'm a bit concerned. Since the `created_at` column is not indexed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row you need to remove the engagement_type from the GROUP BY clause.  however this then won't show you all the different engagement_type's.

If you want to list the engagement_types in one row without duplicating the user details then use the ARRAY_TO_STRING function.  This contaminates the results to one line.  So you could list the engagement types from the comments table as a comma separated list.