# Group_concat equivalent in postgresql 8.2.11

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.2

I am using a older version of Postgres 8.2.11. Can anyone tell me the equivalent of MySql's `group_concat` for this Postgres 8.2.11. I have tried `array_accum` , `array_to_string` , `string_agg` but it doesn't work in this version

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgresql GROUP\_CONCAT equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent)

Comment: @hims056  cant you read the question properly i am asking for 8.2.11 and the possible duplicate question you are showing is for  8.4

Comment: Possible duplicate question is not for 8.4. It's answer is for 8.4.

Comment: @hims056 yup but i need for 8.2.11... so i couldnt find my answer can u give the answer for 8.2.11 please

Comment: @hims056  none of the answers specified in your possible duplicate question doesnt work on 8.2.11.... so please don't try to close the question???

Comment: @soul You're going to need to plan an upgrade Real Soon Now. 8.2 is end-of-life and unsupported, plus you're on an old patch release with quite a few known bugfixes missing. Upgrade promptly to 8.2.23 then start planning an upgrade to 9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["not quite duplicate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent) in the comments should point you in the right direction: [create your own aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createaggregate.html). First you'll need a non-aggregate string concatenation function, something like this:

```
create function concat(t1 text, t2 text) returns text as $$
begin
    return t1 || t2;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Then you can define your own aggregate version of that function:

```
create aggregate group_concat(
    sfunc    = concat,
    basetype = text,
    stype    = text,
    initcond = ''
);
```

Now you can `group_concat` all you want:

```
select group_concat(s)
from t
group by g
```

I dug this out of my archives but I think it should work in 8.2.

Keep in mind that 8.2 is no longer supported so you might want to upgrade to at least 8.4 as soon as possible.

Comment: i need commas in between the group concat result

Comment: @soul: If you want commas in the result then you could modify `concat` to include commas and then add a `finalfunc` to the `create aggregate` which strips off the leading comma with a simple `substring` call. You might also want to read the manual about how NULLs are handled and adjust your aggregate to get the behavior you want.

Comment: the problem with the query now is that it does not take the null values while group concat ... can u give a function which can replace null values with 0

Comment: @soul: You can use [`coalesce`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) for that.

Comment: my outputs shows in this manner   ` 1000046
 smart lite twister 20W 8901399132209 
191.08
 {213.04} {1000001}
1000047
 PARLE 20-20 BUTTER COOKIES(50GM) 8901719904431 
4.46
 {4.73,4.73} {1000001,1000002}`

Comment: see in the last array {100001,100002} is present but in the first row it is just {1000001} ... i need something like {1000001,null or empty}

Comment: @soul: Have you tried anything? Have you read about `coalesce`?