# how to join several row values in one row in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-8.4

**How to turn :**

```
=> SELECT pic.reference, spec.name FROM species spec NATURAL JOIN pictures pic
            WHERE spec.name = 'Bufo bufo';

 reference |   name    
-----------+-----------
 IM000213  | Bufo bufo
 IM000218  | Bufo bufo
 IM000222  | Bufo bufo
 IM000234  | Bufo bufo
(4 lignes)
```

**into something like :**

```
=> ???

 references                           |   name    
--------------------------------------+-----------
 IM000213,IM000218,IM000222,IM000234  | Bufo bufo
(1 ligne)
```

**?**

*note : in postgresql 8.4*

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent

Comment: `string_agg` is your friend.