# PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: At Production Mode in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I am building a web application for which crashes when it is running on production mode @ Heroku and trying to execute the following query whereas in development mode everything is running smoothly.

The query is the following :

```
report_id = ReportsNum.group("report_id").
                    having("GROUP_CONCAT(patent_num ORDER BY patent_num ASC SEPARATOR ',') = ?",patents_list).
                    order(created_at: :desc).
                    pluck(:report_id).
                    first
```

and this is the exception message that I receive :

```
2014-01-08T18:46:48.316625+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SEPARATOR"
2014-01-08T18:46:48.316633+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                               ^
2014-01-08T18:46:48.316637+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "report_patent_nums"."report_id" FROM "report_patent_nums"  GROUP BY report_id HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(patent_num ORDER BY patent_num ASC SEPARATOR ',') = 'AB1234567S1,AB1234567S2'  ORDER BY "report_patent_nums"."created_at" DESC
2014-01-08T18:46:48.316701+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...G GROUP_CONCAT(patent_num ORDER BY patent_num ASC SEPARATOR ...
2014-01-08T18:46:48.316632+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...G GROUP_CONCAT(patent_num ORDER BY patent_num ASC SEPARATOR ...
2014-01-08T18:46:48.316703+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

What could be the reason for this since in the development mode it is running smoothly ?

Could the following warning be the reason for this ?

> [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in
>   the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you
>   can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.

Comment: I don't know how to fix the specific Postgres error you're seeing, but one thing I've found helpful is to develop against the same database you'll be using in production.  It's likely you're developing against SQLite wherease Heroku uses Postgres which can lead to scenarios like you describe.  It takes a little more setup, but it will help you catch problems like this before you push them to production.

Comment: Are your databases identical?

Comment: For the development we are using mysql like stated here in the database.yml file `development:
  adapter: mysql2` . In the production mode we are also using mysql like stated later in the file `production:
  adapter: mysql2` , So they should be identical or not ?

Comment: You can only use postgresql on Heroku.  Regardless of what you specify in your database.yml, Heroku will use a postgres db.

Comment: Heroku runs on Postgresql by default

Comment: So what would you suggest ? Is there any way to identify the reason for this error in Postgresql ?

Answer (score 3):

It is a bad idea to do development using a MySQL database while using a PostgreSQL database in production (i.e. Heroku uses Postgres only, unless you use an add on).

There are significant differences in the implementation of SQL between MySQL and Postgres that will lead to production bugs that are hard to troubleshoot.

For example, I don't think Postgres even has the GROUP_CONCAT method which you are trying to use.

See Heroku's suggestions here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Postgres doesn't have GROUP_CONCAT. [There is a workaround posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent).

This is why you don't develop and deploy on different databases. If you're on a Mac, the easiest way to get going with Postgres is the [Postgres App](http://postgresapp.com).