# Modify the response of a SQL query involving junction table

Tags: sql, postgresql, junction-table

I have two tables linked in a junction table like this :

```
REATE TABLE eventsUsers (
    eventId INT REFERENCES events (eventId),
    userId INT REFERENCES users (userId),
    PRIMARY KEY (eventId, userId)
);
```

I want to return all the events with their user logins. So far I did the following `SQL request` :

```
    SELECT events.eventId, events.name, users.login
    FROM events
    LEFT OUTER JOIN eventsUsers ON events.eventId = eventsUsers.eventId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.userId = eventsUsers.userId
```

And it returns :

```
 eventid |    name    | login 
---------+------------+-------
       1 | event1     | admin
       1 | event1     | user
       2 | deuxieme   | admin
       3 | troisieme3 |
```

But I would like it to return something like this :

```
 eventid |    name    | login 
---------+------------+-------
       1 | event1     | [admin, user]
       2 | deuxieme   | admin
       3 | troisieme3 |
```

With one line for one event and an array (or list) of the user logins.

**So my question is : is it possible to do this in `SQL` and how?**

Edit : I use `Postgresql`.

Comment: In mysql , need to do group by event if and use group concat to get comma separated users

Comment: It might be possible, but it depends on what dbms you are using.

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8803563/781965) that describes how to use the `string_agg` function to do something like what you've asked for.

So to get your result you'd want:

```
SELECT events.eventId, events.name, '[' || string_agg(users.login, ',') || ']'
    FROM events
    LEFT OUTER JOIN eventsUsers ON events.eventId = eventsUsers.eventId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.userId = eventsUsers.userId
GROUP BY events.eventId, events.name
```

Apologies if I've mussed the syntax slightly, I'm actually a SQL Server guy.

Comment: The '[' + doesn't work with postgresql but removing it make it work : it returns "admin,user" and that what I needed, thanks!

Comment: @user3683807 Right, yeah I didn't do my research - you need `||` for concatenation in PostgreSQL