# fetch values into a comma separated string in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

This should be simple one. A query like

```
SELECT code_id FROM code WHERE status = 1
```

gives normally a result like

```
code_id
10
11
12
```

But my goal is to fetch into a string like

```
10,11,12
```

In order to use it in an other query

```
SELECT x FROM table WHERE status in (10,12,13)
```

Preferable in the same query. Is this possible using "standard" Postgresql WITHOUT adding extra extension?

Everything so far is using extension that not are available as standard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever tool you are using just shows you the data like that for convenience. But you can also use the resultset in a [subquery](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-subquery.html), like this

```
SELECT x FROM table WHERE status in (
    SELECT code_id FROM code WHERE status = 1
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way to get result as comma-separated

> > But my goal is to fetch into a string like

```
SELECT string_agg(code_id, ',') FROM code WHERE status = 1
```

Comment: this function does not exist in 9.1 as standard AFAIK. I get an error.

Comment: @sibert: this has been asked before - many times. One of them is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2560946/330315

Comment: Yes, I know. But I could not find an answer using standard extensions. But **SELECT array_to_string(array(SELECT a FROM b),', ')** did work. Thank you!