# How to select columns data in different array objects in SQL?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have following query:

```
select e.name, e.city, d.name, d.area
from employee as e
    inner join department as d on e.id = d.eid;
```

I want the query to get an array response with two array objects.

The first array object **Employee** should contain the following columns: `e.name`, `e.city`.

The second array object **Department** should contain the following columns: `d.name`, `d.area`.

Is there any way to get the data this way? If any so please help me!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Feel free to add the tag(s) for the database you are really using.

Comment: actually i want this in sql and postgres both but main focus on sql

Comment: Use GROUP_CONCAT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat  

maybe here you can resolve your problem   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent

Comment: @BunkerBoy . . . SQL is a language for accessing and managing databases.  Postgres is a database that supports SQL.

Comment: The concept of arrays does not really exist in sql.  If you want to combine two fields, use whatever method exists in your database engine for concatenating fields.  Otherwise, process the results with the application code that is receiving the data.

Comment: does not exist? :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT
    e.name,
    e.city,
    d.name,
    d.area
FROM
    employee AS e,
    department AS d
WHERE
    e.id = d.eid;
```