# laravel eloquent query group by

Tags: php, laravel

I have following structure, just attaching screenshot for reference, consider the attached image is my sql schema

[image]

This is what I am trying to get

```
$array = [
    [
        'city'  =>  1,
        'google'=>  [4,2]
    ],
    [
        'city'  =>  2,
        'google'=>  [3,2,1]
    ],
];
```

I have used **Postgresql**

I tried with group by though no logic behind my implementation, no magic involved in laravel

```
$models = Model::groupBy('city')->get();
```

Can anyone help to find the way?

**Thought of doing it through loop but would like to know the efficient way of doing it.**

Comment: city one should have 4 and 3 as per file,,right?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo yes you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$models = Model::groupBy('city')->selectRaw('city, GROUP_CONCAT(google) as google')->get();
```

Try this out. This would group concat the result for mysql.

```
 $models = Model::groupBy('city')->selectRaw('city, array_agg(google) as google')->get();
```

as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent), there is an alternate for group_concat in Postgres.

Comment: It is postgresql and not mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent
THis contains the equivalent method for group_concat.

Comment: Yes it works, but it is in different format of array like it returns {4,2} instead of [4,2]

Answer (score 1):

You can query directly like this

```
$resultSet =  DB::select(DB::raw(" SQL QUERY HERE"));
```

and in models you can do it like

```
$resultSet = DB::table('table_name')
            ->groupBy('column_name')
            ->get();
```

While in your case you won't need group, you will need `group_concat`. Have a look here 
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Here is what I did:

[image]

For postgreSQL  use this syntax

```
   SELECT city, 
   string_agg(google, ',')
   FROM test
   GROUP BY city
```

Comment: but I don't think this will give me the expected output

Comment: actually it is Postgresql

Comment: string_agg is not a postgresql function it throws exception

Comment: @overflow have a look here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent

Comment: @overflow upvote or mark it as answered if it answered your question..mention postgresql in your question too.