# SQL show only one when register has the same values in 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I am using Postgres and have this query:

```
select d.id,d.santoral_id,d.tipointencion_id from intencion_detalle d
join intencion i ON (i.id=d.intencion_id)
where i.fecha='2017-08-29';
```

and this is the output:
[image]

I want the row 6 and 7 that has the same `santoral_id` and `tipointencion_id` to be **shown only once** not multiple times, and in the same query I want to show the column description that is not in the image but exist in the table. How can I do this?

Comment: how about using `group by` query

Comment: which id you want then? 96 or 97 ?..

Comment: @matQ: kindly paste your final result along with table schema.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql GROUP\_CONCAT equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent)