# Query join two table but another table need to be in another inside array

Tags: javascript, sql

Hello just a question from a newbie i just to query this two 
and i want the second table to be inside the array of the other table.

the table looks like this

post

```
|d : 1"|
|content: "test"|
|id : 2|
|content: "test2"|
```

post_images

```
|id : 1|
|post_id : 1|
|img_name : 1.jpg|
|id : 2|
|post_id : 1|
|img_name : 2.jpg|
|id : 3|
|post_id : 2|
|img_name : 3.jpg|
|id : 4|
|post_id : 2|
|img_name : 2.jpg|
```

My query looks like this

```
Select posts.*,posts_images.* 
from posts 
INNER JOIN posts_images on posts_images.post_id = posts.id
```

is it possible to get this data look like this

```
array
(
   id:1,
   content:test,
   imgs:array
   (
       1.jpg,
       2.jpg
   )
)
```

I hope you understand what I want to say. :) 
looking forward for your help 
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using postgresql? mysql?

Comment: yes postgresql in node js btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My domain is mysql but i have found this info.

[Postgresql GROUP_CONCAT equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent)

You could try:

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.content, array_agg(posts_images.img_name)
FROM posts_images 
INNER JOIN posts on posts_images.post_id = posts.id
GROUP BY posts_images.post_id
```

not sure if aliases work on array_agg but you could try

```
array_agg(img_name) AS imgs
```