# Aggregate rows into one by id - postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate

Example:

```
user_id activity_type interested_rooms
1       views         1,2
1       application   1
1       search        3,2
```

I would like to get result:

```
user_id interested_rooms  
1       "1","2","3"
```

Then I would like to search all users who for example where interested in 1 room

```
SELECT user_id
FROM blabla
WHERE interested_rooms IN "1"
```

How can I get this result by using SQL (`postgreSQL`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql GROUP\_CONCAT equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent)

Comment: Fix your data model!  Numbers should not be stored as strings!  Postgres gives you many other options, such as JSON and arrays and junction tables.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. Considering that your table has the following structure ..

```
CREATE TABLE blabla (user_id INT,activity_type VARCHAR,interested_rooms VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO blabla VALUES (1,'views','1,2'),
                          (1,'application','1'),
                          (1,'search','3,2');
```

.. you could try a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html) ..

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id, unnest(string_to_array(interested_rooms,',')) AS rooms
  FROM blabla ORDER BY rooms
)
SELECT user_id, array_agg(rooms) AS interested_rooms
FROM j GROUP BY user_id
```

.. that would return the result you want

```
 user_id | interested_rooms 
---------+------------------
       1 | {1,2,3}
```

Note that the usage of the functions [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-array.html) and [`string_to_array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-array.html) will depend on the data type of the column `interested_rooms` which wasn't provided in your question. But it should give you an orientation of what to do. Good luck!