# I work with postgresql and i have a database like this

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

```
Col1 Col2
_________
A   |  1
A   |  2
A   |  3
B   |  4
B   |  5
B   |  6
```

and i need to obtain something like this

```
col1 list
________
A   | 1,2,3
B   | 4,5,6
```

i'm still beginner give me the most simple alternative

Comment: You have _table_ like that, not a _database_ (which is a bunch of tables.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Try the following with `array_agg`

```
select
    col1,
    array_agg(col2)
from yourTable
group by
    col1
```

or with `string_agg`

```
select
    col1,
    string_agg(col2, ', ')
from yourTable
group by
    col1
```