# Subquery on SELECT with conditional WHERE clause after it

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have three tables,

`news` :

```
id|title                                                      |body                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |publised_at        |deleted_at|created_at         |
--+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
 1|Tax are Increasing Again, But Why?                         |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor i|                   |          |2021-06-06 14:11:24|
 2|AwanKinton are Making Brand New University Named DragonBall|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor i|                   |          |2021-06-06 14:11:24|
 3|AwanKinton Released New Car that Can Fly                   |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor i|                   |          |2021-06-06 14:11:24|
 4|Indonesia National Team Are Not Gonna Make it to World Cup |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor i|2021-06-06 14:11:24|          |2021-06-06 14:11:24|
10|10 Penyebab Istri Sebel Sama Suami                         |Sebel aslkdjas askldjlsajd alskdjlkas alskdjsalk asldkjaslk asdlkjasld asdljasl asldjsalk alsdjals lajsdlkaj                                                                                                                                                   |                   |          |2021-06-06 14:34:08|
```

`topics` :

```
id|name         |created_at         |
--+-------------+-------------------+
 1|politics     |2021-06-06 18:43:13|
 2|economy      |2021-06-06 18:43:13|
 3|auto         |2021-06-06 18:43:13|
 4|education    |2021-06-06 18:43:13|
 5|tech         |2021-06-06 18:43:13|
 6|culture      |2021-06-06 18:43:13|
 7|money        |2021-06-06 18:43:13|
 8|sports       |2021-06-06 18:43:13|
 9|uncategorized|2021-06-06 18:43:13|
```

and `news_topics` :

```
id|news_id|topics_id|
--+-------+---------+
 1|      1|        7|
 2|      1|        4|
 3|      2|        3|
 4|      2|        4|
 5|      2|        5|
 6|      3|        3|
 7|      3|        4|
 8|      4|        8|
```

And I want to return it like these :

```
id|title                                                      |body                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |published_at|deleted_at|created_at         |t   |
--+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+----+
 1|Tax are Increasing Again, But Why?                         |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor i|            |          |2021-06-06 18:43:13|    |
 2|AwanKinton are Making Brand New University Named DragonBall|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor i|            |          |2021-06-06 18:43:13|auto|
 3|AwanKinton Released New Car that Can Fly                   |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor i|            |          |2021-06-06 18:43:13|auto|
```

I succeed on returning that value using this query

```sql
select "news".*, 
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG("topics"."name", ',') as "topics"
    FROM "topics"
    INNER JOIN "news_topics" ON "topics"."id" = "news_topics"."topics_id"
    WHERE "news_topics"."news_id" = "news"."id"
    AND "topics"."name" IN ('auto')
) AS "topics" 
from "news" 
where published_at IS NULL AND deleted_at IS null 
order by "created_at" 
asc limit 10
```

But there is one flaw to that query, on the above result there are one row that contains null `topics`. When I add `AND topics IS NOT NULL` after it gave me error `SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "topics" does not exist`  it is makes sense because the order of the query SQL executed.

I want rows that had null value on `topics` aren't included on the query result. How do I get that?

Comment: Can you share your schema & data here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Please show example of *null topics* which is not immediate in posted data. Also why is the first news item included in desired results? `news_topics` contains only two instances of auto topics (`topic_id = 3`).

Comment: I think this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561297/2692292

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a correlated subquery to get the column `topics`, aggregate on the joined tables `topics` and `news_topics` and then join to `news`:

```
select n.*, t.topics 
from news n 
inner join (
  SELECT nt.news_id, STRING_AGG(t.name, ',') AS topics
  FROM topics t INNER JOIN news_topics nt
  ON t.id = nt.topics_id
  WHERE t.name IN ('auto')
  GROUP BY nt.news_id
) t ON t.news_id = n.id
where n.published_at IS NULL AND n.deleted_at IS null 
order by n.created_at asc limit 10
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cdc593a9f0852f4cb0ebd3d912ae7e2a).