# Engineer names who work under the same project

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to display list of engineer names who work under the same project. Basically the first column or cell should have multiple `EngineerName` separated by `,` or spaces. In the second column is the `ProjectID` that is common between them. So the output should look like multiple rows of `EngineerName` lists and their common `ProjectID` is the second column.

I used this code and it only displayed single names for each project. Is there a way to display multiple names in one cell ?

```
SELECT e."EngineerName", w."ProjectID"
FROM public."Works_On" as w INNER JOIN public."Engineer" as e
ON w."EngineerID" = e."EngineerID"
GROUP BY e."EngineerName", w."ProjectID"
```

Comment: You can check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, though have not tested:

```
SELECT w.ProjectID, 
       string_agg(e.EngineerName,',')
FROM public.Works_On as w 
INNER JOIN public.Engineer as e
ON w.EngineerID" = e.EngineerID
GROUP BY w.ProjectID
```