# How to create group comma-separated integers in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I have given SQL-query

```
SELECT  * FROM (SELECT * FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN Product 
ON Customer.Ids = Product.CustomerId) as a
```

And here IS output that I have:

| Customer_ids | name | gender | age | phone | ids | Customer_ids | productcode | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ruslan | Male | 14 | 43214 | 1 | 1 | Milk | 200 |
| 1 | Ruslan | Male | 14 | 43214 | 2 | 1 | Butter | 105 |
| 1 | Ruslan | Male | 14 | 43214 | 3 | 1 | Bread | 110 |
| 2 | Alex | Female | 19 | 324323 | 4 | 2 | Bread | 112 |
| 2 | Alex | Female | 19 | 324323 | 5 | 2 | Potato | 112 |
| 2 | Alex | Female | 19 | 324323 | 6 | 2 | Mango | 320 |
| 3 | John | Male | 21 | 32433 | 7 | 3 | Bread | 112 |
| 3 | John | Male | 21 | 32433 | 8 | 3 | Fork | 230 |
| 4 | Sandra | Female | 14 | 32412 | 9 | 4 | Package | 235 |
| 4 | Sandra | Female | 14 | 32412 | 10 | 4 | Cucumber | 236 |

I need to get a a query with Customer_ids and a list of productcode per Customer_Ids

[Expected Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAWGf.png)

Comment: (1) Your code has useless outer query. (2) Please add the expected result to your question (just [Edit] it).

Comment: can you share your best coding attempt at this problem? ("*finding the list of productcode per Customer_Ids*")

Comment: This is a job for [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) in MySQL.

Comment: @PM77-1 just added it. I had to use query, because in the beginning it was two tables

Comment: @O.Jones what are some alternative for PostgreSQL?

Comment: @РусланПилипюк: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent