# Understanding syntax error at or near "SEPARATOR" after migrating from MySQL to Postgres

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql, heroku

I recently had to overhaul a Django project that originally used MySQL, but in order to deploy to Heroku (as per their recommendations in their [docs regarding Django deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup)) I migrated the MySQL database to Postgres via the following method:

1. Installed dependencies: `pyscopg2` and `py-mysql2pgsql`
2. Setup Postgres database
3. Migrated data base: `$ py-mysql2pgsql` — this creates a `mysql2pgsql.yml` file, which looks like this:

   `mysql:
     hostname: localhost
     port: 3306
     socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
     username: foo
     password: bar
     database: your_database_name
     compress: false
   destination:
     postgres:
       hostname: localhost
       port: 5432
       username: foo
       password: bar
       database: your_database_name`
4. Transferred the data via: `$ py-mysql2pgsql -v -f mysql2pgsql.yml`

After many cups of coffee, the deployment to Heroku was successful (for the most part, until I discovered this issue today) and the app works as expected on heroku and when I run `$ heroku local`. But today, when accessing a certain a function on the front end, an error with the database appeared in the browser:

```
DatabaseError at /projects/

syntax error at or near "SEPARATOR"
LINE 1: ...s, sc.name as sport_category, string_agg(au.email SEPARATOR ...
                                                             ^

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:8989/projects/
Django Version:     1.5.1
Exception Type:     DatabaseError
Exception Value:    

syntax error at or near "SEPARATOR"
LINE 1: ...s, sc.name as sport_category, string_agg(au.email SEPARATOR ...
```

I believe that the relevant code is in a file called business.py:

```
def getAllProjects(self):
        '''
        @note: Retrieve all projects
        '''

        from django.db import connection
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        cursor.execute("select p.id, p.title, p.description, p.deadline, pt.name as project_type, s.name as status, sc.name as sport_category, group_concat(au.email SEPARATOR '\n') as project_managers from project p left join project_manager_in_project pmip on p.id = pmip.project_id left join auth_user au on pmip.project_manager_id = au.id inner join project_type pt on p.projectType_id = pt.id inner join status s on p.status_id = s.id inner join sport_category sc on p.sportCategory_id = sc.id where p.deleted = 0 group by p.id")
        projects = cursor.fetchall()
        return projects
```

I'm aware of a few posts that talk about similar issues:

[Postgresql - concat_ws like function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943433/postgresql-concat-ws-like-function)

[Postgresql GROUP_CONCAT equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent)

Which led me to try and change `group_concat(au.email SEPARATOR '\n')` to `string_agg(au.email SEPARATOR '\n')` and then `array_agg(au.email SEPARATOR '\n')` but I'm still getting the same error.

Is there another way I should approach this and adjust this function to effect a workaround?

**UPDATE**: for anyone who's interested, the selected answer (and comments) provided by Consider Me below led me to the following altered query statement which works with no issues thus far:

```
cursor.execute("select \"project\".\"id\", project.title, project.description, \"project\".\"deadline\", \"pt\".\"name\" as \"project_type\", \"sc\".\"name\" as status, \"sc\".\"name\" as sport_category, string_agg(au.email, E'\n') as project_managers from project left join project_manager_in_project pmip on project.id = pmip.project_id left join auth_user au on pmip.project_manager_id = au.id inner join project_type pt on project.\"projectType_id\" = pt.id inner join status s on project.\"status_id\" = \"s\".id inner join sport_category sc on \"project\".\"sportCategory_id\" = \"sc\".\"id\" where project.deleted = 0 group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7")
```

As the original developer of this app has created all the tables with double quotes, this led to the `column p.projecttype_id does not exist` error and other similar `does not exist` errors I kept getting when all I had done was deleted `SEPARATOR` and changed `group_concat` (neither of which exist in Postgres) to `string_agg`. In other words, as per Consider Me's suggestion, I had to encapsulate with double quotes pretty much all the table and column names (and escape the quotes of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already seen you need to replace `GROUP_CONCAT()` with `STRING_AGG()`. Include every column that is not used inside an aggregate function in `GROUP BY` clause.

```
select 
  p.id, 
  p.title, 
  p.description, 
  p.deadline, 
  pt.name as project_type, 
  s.name as status, 
  sc.name as sport_category, 
  string_agg(au.email, E'\n') as project_managers 
from 
  project p 
  left join project_manager_in_project pmip on p.id = pmip.project_id 
  left join auth_user au on pmip.project_manager_id = au.id 
  inner join project_type pt on p.projectType_id = pt.id 
  inner join status s on p.status_id = s.id 
  inner join sport_category sc on p.sportCategory_id = sc.id
where 
  p.deleted = 0 
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

There is no `SEPARATOR` keyword in Postgres (at least I'm not aware of its' existence).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Now I'm getting this error message in the browser when trying to load that page: `column p.projecttype_id does not exist
LINE 2: ..._manager_id = au.id inner join project_type pt on p.projectT...`

Comment: Error is pretty straightforward. You don't have a column in your table that you're referring to (projecttype_id in table project)

Comment: Except that there is a `projectType_id` column (type Integer) in the `project` table, hence my confusion.

Comment: Maybe there is a `"projectType_id"` column, but not `projectType_id`. Try encapsulating that name with double quotes. This would correspond to backticks that are commonly used in MySQL.

Comment: Further errors you're receiving are not a fit for this question. Create a new one and if my answer was helpful in resolving the issue from your question, you can mark is as accepted.